# Using DataConnectionDialog

Tags: database-connection

When I am attempting to use the DataConnectionDialog from NuGet (version 1.2), I receive the Advanced Settings dialog for setting up the Database Connection.  Is there some Setting I have missed or additional library to retreive?

Code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI;

DataConnectionDialog dcd = new DataConnectionDialog();
DataSource.AddStandardDataSources(dcd);
dcd.SelectedDataSource = DataSource.SqlDataSource;
dcd.SelectedDataProvider = DataProvider.SqlDataProvider;
DataConnectionDialog.Show(dcd);
```

Output:

[image]

What I want (this comes from the datasource wizard in Visual Studio Community 2015):

[image]

Comment: I have similar code and I'm getting the second dialog box as expected. Maybe other settings that you have configured or coded code be influencing this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I happened to stumble on the same issue. From my main form, I called an `async` method using `Task.Factory.StartNew`. This method tries to open the Data Connection Dialog but it would show the Advance Settings dialog box instead.

During troubleshooting, I replaced the `DataConnectionDialog` with a `OpenFileDialog` and this gave me a `ThreadStateException` which pointed me towards the solution.

To solve it, I had to put the code in a separate function, e.g. `AskConnectionString` and call it using [Control.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx).

e.g.

```vb
public void btnConnString_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _connectionString = (string)this.Invoke(AskConnectionString);
}

public string AskConnectionString()
{
    DataConnectionDialog dcd = new DataConnectionDialog();
    DataSource.AddStandardDataSources(dcd);
    dcd.SelectedDataSource = DataSource.SqlDataSource;
    dcd.SelectedDataProvider = DataProvider.SqlDataProvider;
    DataConnectionDialog.Show(dcd);

    return dcd.ConnectionString;
}
```